# Difference between strong and weak property in scrolling image

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application I have one scrollview and I set twenty images in subview.

When I set weak property of image view like this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageofScrollView;
```

ImageView not displaying any of the images.

When I set strong property of that image view like below

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageofScrollView;
```

then all images are displaying properly.

I can not understand what's happening in this property?

```
for (int i = 0; i <[Array count]; i++)
    {
        //set frame for scroll view image
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.y = self.ScrollView.frame.size.height/2 * i;
        frame.origin.x = self.ImageofScrollView.frame.origin.x;
        frame.size.height = self.ScrollView.frame.size.height/2;
        frame.size.width=self.ImageofScrollView.frame.size.width;

        NSMutableDictionary *mudi=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        mudic=[Array objectAtIndex:i];

            self.ImageofScrollView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
            self.ImageofScrollView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            [commonUtils setImageViewAFNetworking:_ImageofScrollView withImageUrl:[mudic objectForKey:@"logourl"] withPlaceholderImage:nil];
            [self.ScrollViewaddSubview:self.ImageofScrollView];

    }
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how the images and image views are created and added.

Comment: here is my updated code

Comment: Why do you use a property for `ImagefoScrollView` inside the loop? In the end you will only have a reference to the last image view.

Comment: if I remove ImageofScroller property then image not desplaying

Comment: Just use a local variable. `UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];`. No need for the property.

Comment: This working Thanks @rmaddy

Comment: Could you please add a simple explanation as an answer @rmaddy. It would help us understanding about the properties!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is the misuse of the image view property. It's simply not needed in your code. Use a local variable inside the loop as follows:

```
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [Array count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *mudic = Array[i];

    //set frame for scroll view image
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.y = self.ScrollView.frame.size.height/2 * i;
    frame.origin.x = self.ImageofScrollView.frame.origin.x;
    frame.size.height = self.ScrollView.frame.size.height/2;
    frame.size.width = self.ImageofScrollView.frame.size.width;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [commonUtils setImageViewAFNetworking:imageView withImageUrl:mudic[@"logourl"] withPlaceholderImage:nil];
    [self.ScrollViewaddSubview:imageView];
}
```

A few other points:

1. Variable and method names should begin with lowercase letters. Class names begin with uppercase letters. (rename your `Array` variable to `array`, for example).
2. Use proper data types. The loop variable should be `NSInteger`, not `int` since all of the `NSArray` methods use `NSInteger`, not `int`.
3. Use modern syntax. It's easier to read and write.
4. You were needlessly allocating a wasted array for your `mudic` variable.

---

Even though you were misusing a property for this, I suspect your code would have worked with the `weak` property if you switched these two lines from:

```
[commonUtils setImageViewAFNetworking:_ImageofScrollView withImageUrl:[mudic objectForKey:@"logourl"] withPlaceholderImage:nil];
[self.ScrollViewaddSubview:self.ImageofScrollView];
```

to:

```
[self.ScrollViewaddSubview:self.ImageofScrollView];
[commonUtils setImageViewAFNetworking:_ImageofScrollView withImageUrl:[mudic objectForKey:@"logourl"] withPlaceholderImage:nil];
```

This may have helped because adding the image view as a subview would have kept a strong reference. But this is really moot because you shouldn't have been doing it that way at all.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a property as strong is asking the system to guarantee that the referred object will be there as long as you are there. This can lead to memory leaks if you have cyclic strong relationships. That is the reason to declare an object as weak: it means you don't need this guarantee. Most of the time  you will do this when you know that some other object will have a strong relationship to the referred object, so you are sure it will be there. You do this to prevent circular strong relationships. So: A - strong -> B and B - strong -> C and C - strong -> A means that none of the objects will be deallocated. So you make at least one of those relationships weak. In your case when you declare the subviews as weak then the system is free to deallocate them if no other object has a strong relationship to them. So it deallocates them before you can see them.